# use a table of lists as tensorflow input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow

I am trying to feed a tensorflow model and my table has a format like this:

| index | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `[1,2,3]` | `[1,2,3]` | `[1,2,3]` |
| 2 | `[1,2,3]` | `[1,2,3]` | `[1,2,3]` |
| 3 | `[1,2,3]` | `[1,2,3]` | `[1,2,3]` |
| 4 | `[1,2,3]` | `[1,2,3]` | `[1,2,3]` |

but it returns this error:

> ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).

How can I make to feed it?
Need I to change the table format?

Comment: How you feed the df to tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've correctly understood your question, this should work in your case. But it only works if every element in your dataframe as the same length. Here the `sum` will concatenate each row into a single list, then you reconstruct by reshaping the resulted array.

```
num_cols = len(df.columns)
num_rows = len(df)

res = list(df.sum(axis=1).to_numpy())
# Define which shape you want
res = np.reshape(res, (num_rows, num_cols, -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing lists, but you need arrays:

```
import numpy as np

df['a'] = df['a'].apply(np.array)
df['b'] = df['b'].apply(np.array)
df['c'] = df['c'].apply(np.array)
```